# Writing a function that checks if the parameter is an object literal OR a function OR a string value

Tags: javascript

I was learning ngMock and realized that the module method of ngMock takes an argument that can be either a string, OR a function OR an object literal. I was wondering what is the best way to write a similar function using just plain JavaScript and doing the following:

```
// PSEUDO CODE
    function(argument){
      if(argument is function){
                 console.writeline('Function');
           }
        else if(argument is object){
               console.writeLine('Object');
          }
        else if(argument is string){
              console.writeLine('String literal');
        }
    }
```

Comment: "object literal" is not a value. It's a literal which produces an object value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to test whether `value` is

**A function**

- Callable object

  ```
  typeof value === 'function'
  ```
- Instance of Function

  ```
  value instanceof Function
  ```
- Callable instance of Function

  ```
  typeof value === 'function' && value instanceof Function
  ```

Examples:

- Callable non-instance of Function: `document.createElement('object')`
- Non-callable instance of Function: `Object.create(Function.prototype)`
- Callable instance of Function: `function(){}`

**An object**

- Object

  ```
  Object(value) === value
  ```
- Non-callable object

  ```
  Object(value) === value && typeof value !== 'function'
  ```
- Instance of Object

  ```
  value instanceof Object
  ```

Examples:

- Callable instance of Object: `function(){}`
- Non-callable instance of Object: `[]`
- Non-callable non-instance of Object: `Object.create(null)`

Note that `typeof value === 'object'` is not a reliable way to detect objects, because

- It produces false negatives for callable objects
- It produces false positives for `null`
- It may produce false negatives for non-callable host objects

**A string**

- Primitive string

  ```
  typeof value === 'string'
  ```
- Instance of String

  ```
  value instanceof String
  ```
- String exotic object (may produce false positives)

  ```
  ({}).toString.call(value) === "[object String]" && typeof value !== 'string'
  ```

Examples:

- Primitive string: `"abc"`
- String exotic object instance of String: `new String("abc")`
- Non-string exotic object instance of String: `Object.create(String.prototype)`

Comment: your approach seems more bullet proof. How about the efficency of this approach and browser compatibitly ?

Comment: @ATHER I don't think any of these tests costs much. Browser compatibility should be OK, but be aware ECMAScript3 didn't require `typeof value` to be `"function"` for callable host objects.

Answer (score 3):

Use **[typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)**

```
function(argument){
  if(typeof  argument == 'function'){
       console.log('Function');
   }
   else if(typeof argument == 'object'){
       console.log('Object');
   }
   else if(typeof argument == 'string'){
       console.log('String literal');
   }
}
```

Or better yet

```
function(argument){
   console.log(typeof argument);
}
```

Comment: You really should not have the () after typeof

Comment: `typeof` is not a reliable way to detect objects.

Comment: @Oriol: interesting claim. Why not? (Feel free to make it part of your own answer so it does not get buried in a comment.)

Comment: @Jongware `typeof ==  'object'` fails for `null` and callable objects, and the result is implementation-dependent for non-callable host objects.